# Trying to make the shortened link for my website go into a textarea or textbox

Tags: php, textarea

I am a learning student creating a URL shortener for me and a few friends online, and I am having issues trying to make the shortened URL go into a textarea instead of just regular text.

I have attempted to add HTML with the textarea code then I entered my code, but it didnt work and it just broke.

```
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO links (`url`, `title`) VALUES ('$url', '$title')");
echo "Your link: <a href='http://clicky.tk/".$title."'>http://clicky.tk/".$title."</a>";
```

I am trying to get the final http://clicky.tk/string to go to a textarea or textbox instead of just plain text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dropping your new link into a `<textarea></textarea>` or `<input type="text">` is what you're looking for.

Example:

```
echo "Your link: <input type='text' value='http://clicky.tk/" . $title . "'>";
or
echo "Your link: <textarea>http://clicky.tk/" . $title . "</textarea>";
```

The link won't be clickable, but it will be in a text box.

Also, while we're at it - since it looks like you're using PDO, you might want to look into [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead of just direct queries.  It's much safer.